# unrecognized option: tls.mode

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, terminal, yaml

I'm currently at MongoDB University. Does anyone solve this error **unrecognized option: tls.mode** when taking a curriculum there at ***M103 Basic Cluster Administration***. I fill the **mongod.conf** file:

```
storage:
  dbPath: "/data/db"
systemLog:
  path: "/data/log/mongod.log"
  destination: "file"
replication:
  replSetName: M103
net:
  port: 27000
  bindIp : "127.0.0.1,192.168.103.100"
tls:
  mode: "requireTLS"
  certificateKeyFile: "/etc/tls/tls.pem"
  CAFile: "/etc/tls/TLSCA.pem"
security:
  keyFile: "/data/keyfile"
  authorization: enabled
processManagement:
  fork: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option should be `net.tls.mode`, i.e. it should be nested under `net` like

```
net:
  port: 27000
  bindIp : "127.0.0.1,192.168.103.100"
  tls:
    mode: "requireTLS"
    certificateKeyFile: "/etc/tls/tls.pem"
    CAFile: "/etc/tls/TLSCA.pem"
```